# how to make my random gaussiana distribution over one day

Tags: python, numpy, random, gaussian

I would like to simulate a random normal distribution using python but in the x-axis, I would like that the distribution was centered in the 14:00 hs, for example. I have some idea where my distribution will be centered.

My function will receive a timestamp and return a value which belongs to the Gaussian function. [Using this](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.normal.html)

Comment: Did you read the first two parameters to the function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can calculate a random distribution with loc 14 and scale 12 (+- 12 hours) and then add it as a pandas timedelta of type hours. So given your timestamp it would be

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
timestamp + pd.Timedelta(np.random.normal(14,12),'h')
```

That should do the trick.

**Edit**

If you want to get a value out of the gaussian distribution around the hour of the timestamp you could use something like this:

```
timestamp = pd.Timestamp('20180426140000')
np.random.normal(timestamp.hour,12)
```

and if you want to include the minutes

```
timestamp.hour + timestamp.minute/60
```

Of course, if you need more of one value of the distribution, then you can supply it with the third parameter

```
np.random.normal(timestamp.hour,12,10000)
```

Comment: Hallo, Marvin. This actually returns a data time object and I need to return the values of my gaussiana

Comment: So you want to input a timestamp and then return the values of a gaussian around the hour of the timestamp?

Comment: so I want to do a function that would have the format of a gaussian or bell format with centered in 14:00pm and highest value at 3 in y-axis. But yeah the function will receive a time (hours in a day) and give back a number that belongs to this curve

Comment: Ok, now I'm actually more confused about what you are trying to do.  
np.random.normal returns a random sample of a given gaussian distribution, so just an "x". Then there are functions like scipy.stats.norm that will return the probability density of a given "x".  
But the probability cannot, by definition, exceed 1. You could of course build a gaussian curve that has a maximum at 3 or even transform the pdf so that the maximal value is 3, but why exactly are you trying to achieve that?